# How can I modify PKStrokes before canvasViewDidEndUsingTool is called?

Tags: swift, ios14, pencilkit

I'd like to implement something to straighten lines when the user holds the pencil in one place at the end of the stroke, however I don't have access to the PKStrokes to modify until they release the pencil from the iPad.  Apple's version of this in their apps changes the strokes in place prior to the pencil being lifted.  I've tried implementing a long press gesture recognizer, but that didn't seem to get called.

Has anyone done this with success? I might be missing something very straightforward, but it seems like the canvasView is intercepting everything.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?